# Chrome not sending FormsAuthentication cookie in the subsequent API request

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

I can see forms authentication cookie coming back as a response in one of the requests, however it is not sent by Chrome in the subsequent API request which causes those requests to fail, i.e sending back 401 Unauthorized. This happens only for a few end users in Chrome. Most of the affected users are able to use the application in IE without any issues.

Comment: Please specify a bit the context, which part of these do you develop ?
the server side, the client ?

Comment: We are using ext.js for the presentation layer and ASP.NET Web API's for the backend. I work on both front end and back end.